# LEFT Formula, Find "-" or "+" and return the characters before it

Tags: microsoft-excel

In column A I have records that have either + or minus at the end of them. Like this:

`Stack+` or `Overflow-`.

I am trying to parse both so I just get the words.
I am able to parse them using this `=LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1)` but this only works for the `-`.
Does anyone know a more dynamic formula for both?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `+` and `-` are always at the end, you don't need to `find` them. The below formula will work

```
=LEFT(B2, LEN(B2) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=LEFT(A2,MIN(FIND({"+","-"},A2&"+-"))-1)
```

[image]